# Explain the meaning of X02AJF(0.D0)

Tags: math, fortran

If I have this function in fortran

```
DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION         X02AJF()


 !     RETURNS  (1/2)*B**(1-P)  IF ROUNDS IS .TRUE.


!     RETURNS  B**(1-P)  OTHERWISE
 
      DOUBLE PRECISION X02CON 

      DATA X02CON / 2.D-3 /

!     .. Executable Statements ..

      X02AJF = X02CON

      RETURN

      END
```

then what is the value of this variable

`EPS = X02AJF(0.D0)`

I can't know what mean this

`X02AJF(0.D0)`???

Is it mean `EPS=0` ??

Comment: According to NAG [documentation](https://www.nag.com/numeric/fl/nagdoc_fl25/html/x02/x02ajf.html), `X02AJF` takes *no* arguments/parameters, so it should be called as `X02AJF ()`

Comment: but there is many program use this expression    EPS = X02AJF(0.D0)

Comment: as example this program in the following link                              http://www.netlib.org/toms-2014-06-10/775

Comment: `X02AJF` was introduced with Mark 12 of the NAG library. I cannot find documentation for a version that old. Internet-accessible NAG library documentation back to mark 19 shows `X02AJF` as having no arguments/parameters.

Comment: Some programmers using `X02AJF` may have been confused, because older functions in the same section take a dummy parameter, e.g. `X02AHF`. My question is: Is your code actually using the NAG library, or is it supplying it's own home-brew substitute for `X02AJF`?

Comment: I got it from  my friend , frankly I'm beginner in fortran

Answer (score 0):

> I can't know what mean this
>
> X02AJF(0.D0)???

In strict accordance with the FORTRAN language, this is a wrong function call.

> Is it mean EPS=0 ??

No. EPS == 2.D-3, but this is undefined behavior.

Informally, before the OPTIONAL attribute Fortran 90, many often violated the requirement of matching the number of arguments. For example, the System V ABI AMD64 defines a call to the FORTRAN function as similar to a call to the C function. Therefore, in this case, the result of X02AJF(0.D0) will be the same as X02AJF().